# Is it possible to make an alias for a git remote name

Tags: git

I'd like to alias `origin` to `o` and `upstream` to `u`.

I know that I can rename them and just use `o` and `u`, but ideally both long and short version would work.

I do realize there are "git aliases", but these are aliasing whole commands (AFAIK). And I just want to make an alias that works in all commands and for all other purposes.

Is it possible?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not something Git supports. The closest solution I can think of would be Zsh global aliases (which expand in any context, not just command position), but even those won't take context into account: `o` would expand to `origin` *everywhere* `o` is used as a complete word, not just when used as an argument in a Git command.

Comment: what commands do you have in mind ? `fetch` and `push` are easily turned into specialized aliases. I don't know of a clean way to have aliases for remote branches (and I don't think git supports one), you could try your luck with `ln -nsf origin .git/refs/remotes/o`, but there are probably a load of foot shooters hidden behind that hack :D

Comment: Seems like you could do `git remote add o $(git remote get-url origin)`, or just name the remote `o` in the first place.

Comment: Isn't having two names for same url going to track them separately when I `git fetch o`, but not `git fetch origin`?